# checked radio button after tr onclick in pure javascript. Performace also matter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been searching many times on how to check radio button in tr onclick in pure javascript but I only see Jquery. Can someone convert this jquery code to pure javascript or any will do. Performance also matter. Any help will be greatly appreciated

```
$('tr').click(
   function() {
        $('input[type=radio]',this).attr('checked','checked');
   }
);
```

My html. I use radio buttons in selecting a record in the table before deleting or updating it. When a user clicks a row, I want my radio button to be selected in pure javascript and not Jquery because perfomance matter

```
<tr onclick="myfunc(this)">
    <td><input type="radio" name="rd" value="somevalue"></td>
    <td>some text</td>
    <td>another text</td>
</tr>
<tr onclick="myfunc(this)">
    <td><input type="radio" name="rd" value="somevalue"></td>
    <td>some text</td>
    <td>another text</td>
</tr>
<tr onclick="myfunc(this)">
    <td><input type="radio" name="rd" value="somevalue"></td>
    <td>some text</td>
    <td>another text</td>
</tr>
<!-- more tr -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    function myfunc(o){
        o.onclick = function() {

            // code goes here
            o.("input[type=radio]").checked = true; //something like this
        }

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Add your `html` too.

Comment: StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), and we also [don't answer homework questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: I've edited the question and added my html. Sorry for the lack of details, I am new here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made an example for you. It's consisted of `two radio groups`. The top one is alone in it's own row while the bottom radio group is made of two radio buttons each in it's own cell.

All you have to do is pass the `id` of the radio you wish to alter. Like this (run the snippet):

```js
function checkMe(id)
{
  document.getElementById(id).checked = true;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" cellspacing="0">
<tr onclick="checkMe('radio1')">
  <td colspan="2"><input type="radio" name="radioFirst" id="radio1" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td onclick="checkMe('radio2')"><input type="radio" name="radioSecond" id="radio2" /></td>
  <td onclick="checkMe('radio3')"><input type="radio" name="radioSecond" id="radio3" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: what if i have many radiobuttons like 20k or more. I use radiobuttons in selecting a record in my table. I also want better performance

Comment: @NightFury.exe I don't think it can get any faster than this. `Note:` for different radio groups use different radio `names`. Radio buttons that belong to the `same group` should have the `same name` like `name="radioGroup1"`.

Comment: @NightFury.exe Please set the answer as accepted if it worked for you. Thanks

Comment: But I have only 1 radio group. Please see my edited question :)

Comment: No problem, give them all the same name :) If you have any trouble ping me. Peace